# How to find all instances of string and replace it with numbered strings?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have this string:

```
Test abcdeftTest 12Test35
```

I need to find all Test instances and then replace them with numbered strings like Test1, Test2, Test3. I can get the string instances using match but I'm not sure how to replace each one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply achieve this result using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

First, declare a `count` variable and initialize it with `0`. Use replace it to replace the `Test` by passing the second parameter as a function whose return value will be the replaced value in the string.

```js
const str = "Test abcdeftTest 12Test35";

let count = 0;
const result = str.replace(/Test/g, () => `Test${++count}`);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const str = "Test abcdeftTest 12Test35 Test555";
    
    const result = str.match(/Test/g);
    console.log(  result );
    var numberofOccurence = result.length;
    
    console.log( " Number of Test found in string   " +numberofOccurence)
    
       
    
    for(var i=0; i <= numberofOccurence-1; i++){
    
    
       console.log( str.replace(/Test/g,   () => `Test___${i}`)  )
    
    }
```

Hope this will work for you. :)

Answer (score -1):

**This can help you**

```js
"Test abcdeftTest 12Test35".replaceAll(/test/gi,"example")
```

Comment: This doesn't help because this will replace all occurrences of `test` with specific text (`example` here) that OP doesn't want.